# Exclude Item from Web-Scraped Loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have the following `html`:

```
<h4>
     <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</h4>
<h4>Random Text</h4>
```

I am able to identify all `h4` headings via a loop such as:

```
for url in soup.findAll("h4")
    print(url.get_text())
```

And that works well except it includes the "random text" element of the `h4` heading.  Is it possible to programmatically remove occurrences of `h4` headings that do not meet a certain criteria - for example, those that don't contain a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can go with a straightforward approach, simply filtering the headings:

```
for url in soup.find_all("h4")
    if not url.a:  # "url.a" is a shortcut to "url.find('a')"
        continue
    print(url.get_text())
```

Or, a better way would be to filter them with a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
for url in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "h4" and tag.a):
    print(url.get_text())
```

Or, even better, go straight to the `a` elements:

```
for url in soup.select("h4 > a"):
    print(url.get_text())
```

`h4 > a` here is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that would match `a` elements that are direct children of `h4` tags.

Comment: Or `if url.a:print(url.get_text())`

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension as the most pythonic approach:

```
[i.get_text() for i in soup.findAll("h4") if #Insert criteria here#]
```

Comment: While using list comprehension is nice and is applicable in this case, this does not answer the question the OP is asking..better for this answer to be a comment imho.

Comment: Which part of the question does it not answer?

Comment: Okay, no offense here, of course, but where in the answer you are filtering the headings that don't contain links?

Comment: And, it is not "list iteration", it is "list comprehension".

Comment: OP asked for a general criteria. As I clearly pointed out in the code, he can insert his general criteria at the end. And thanks for pointing out my error. Enjoy your ego power trip. Not sure why it kills you to have another answer.

Comment: Nah, that's far from being a problem for me. Here is your upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Likewise. I didn't have a problem with your answer. Just nice to have multiple ways to attack problems.